# Error in sending AT commands in esp8266 connecting to arduino IDE

Tags: esp8266

I am working on esp8266 with Arduino.

I have connected pins like arduino-esp 3.3-vcc
gnd-gnd 3.3-CH_PD RX-TX TX-RX  and reset to gnd using 3k resistor.

I couldn't send AT commands in serial monitor in Arduino IDE.

Later I connected a capacitor between Vcc and Gnd. Now I could send AT commands and I am getting same commands back. Whatever I entered, I am getting the same back.

I didn't get reply as OK. And I got some random characters too. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think TX needs to go to TX and RX to RX, if you are sending the command via the computer instead of the arduino-sketch. You also need to convert the 5v to 3.3v on the RX line.

Comment: `You also need to convert the 5v to 3.3v on the RX line.` - s/he needs to do *what*?

Comment: `I have connected pins like arduino-esp 3.3-vcc gnd-gnd 3.3-CH_PD RX-TX TX-RX and reset to gnd using 3k resistor.` - you connected what to what? This is very unclear. Please edit your question and clarify what you have done. Also try to write proper English if possible. Sentences start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your connection is somewhere missing.

Connect CH_PD and reset pin to high--i.e. 3.3v.

Comment: Please do not insert advertisements into your post. You are welcome to add this to your profile page, but not into the post itself. I've edited it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I made the following connection with Arduino Mega 2560 and AT commands was working perfectly well.

**Connection:**

ESP8266 - Arduino Mega 2560

Vcc, CH_PD, RST - 3.3V pin

GND - GND

Rx - Tx(18)

Tx - Rx(19)

**Program:**

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);   // USB serial port of Due (PROGRAMMING)
  Serial1.begin(115200);  // ESP8266 on Serial Port 1 of Due (UART 1)
}

char rx_byte = 0;

void loop() {
  // send terminal byte to ESP8266
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    rx_byte = Serial.read();
    Serial1.print(rx_byte);
  }
  // send ESP8266 byte to terminal
  if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
    rx_byte = Serial1.read();
    Serial.print(rx_byte);
  }
}
```

Select Tools>Board> Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560. Upload the code. In serial monitor, select 115200 baud rate and Both NL & CR option.
Enter the AT command and it works!